# Stress on pulling in MD simulation

Tags: gromacs, plumed

In gromacs, if we use SMD to pull one end of the molecule, how can we compute the stress applied if we know the force. I am using plumed to define a colvar, and pulling one end of my molecule. Thanks.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, even though this appears to be a very "low-effort" question. You didn't even put a question mark after "how can we compute the stress applied if we know the force". Have you figured out the answer to this yet? Is it still a problem for you? Please update us!